# Print PDF which generated Dynamically without print dialog in silvelright

Tags: c#, silverlight, pdf, mvvm, printing

I know we can print page without print dialog box from one of my question in below link

[Print Grid which generated dynamically in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040735/print-grid-which-generated-dynamically-in-wpf)

but right now my problem is I want to print PDF file without print dialogbox, because from above link i print Grid not a PDF doc and i am creating PDF file from rdl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight 4 you cannot print anything without showing the Print dialog box. It is a security restriction that cannot be overridden.

Comment: So i have to open PDF and then user can print that manually, that way i have to do?

Comment: Yes, you have to open the PDF in browser or using Adobe Reader and then the user will print it manually.

Comment: i m creating PDF file dynamically from sqlserver reporting fle (.RDL) file and i think we have not response object in viewmodel, so can i open PDF from silverlight project directly?