# How to align children items in canvas to print with gridspan

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to print out a grid span of items. I assigned all the items within the gridspan to a parent canvas. But they keep aligning to the `mainCanvasFinal` when I want them to be aligned within the grid. Note: `mainCanvasFinal` is the parent.

```
       mainCavasFinal.Children.Add(mainCanvas);
        Grid.SetRow(mainCanvas, 5);
        Grid.SetColumn(mainCanvas, 1);


       mainCavasFinal.Children.Add(mainCanvas1);
        Grid.SetRow(mainCanvas1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(mainCanvas1, 1);

       myGrid.Children.Add(mainCavasFinal);
        Grid.SetRow(mainCavasFinal, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(mainCavasFinal, 0);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(mainCavasFinal, 6);
       Grid.SetColumnSpan(mainCavasFinal,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting Grid.SetRow and Grid.SetColumn attached properties works only if specified object is wrapped in Grid. In your case your mainCanvas1 and mainCanvas are wrappep in mainCavasFinal. So only mainCavasFinal is affected by Grid attached properties.

If you want to use Canvas container you can manage its children position using Canvas methods:
`Canvas.SetLeft(mainCanvas, 100);
 Canvas.SetTop(mainCanvas, 100);`

or you can pring Grid itself, see: [Print Grid which generated dynamically in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040735/print-grid-which-generated-dynamically-in-wpf)