# Grid not printing content

Tags: c#, wpf

The button is placed in a second grid. The first grid contains the content I want to print
However when I print the first grid doesn't show anything and is printing a blank document

Button and grid code:

```
        Button Print = new Button();
        Print.Content = "Print";
        Print.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(OnPrintClick);

        secondGrid.Children.Add(Print);
        Grid.SetColumn(Print, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(Print, 5);
        ColumnDefinition myColumsecondGrid = new ColumnDefinition();
            RowDefinition myRowsecondGrid = new RowDefinition();



           myRowsecondGrid.Height = new GridLength(300);
             myColumsecondGrid.Width = new GridLength(165);



             secondGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = myColumsecondGrid.Width });
             secondGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = myRow.Height });
```

Button print code:

```
                 private void OnPrintClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

        PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();




        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            //System.Printing
            //get selected printer capabilities
           System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);



            //get the size of the printer page
            Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

            // update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
            myGrid.Measure(sz);
            myGrid.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

            //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
            //printDlg.PageRangeSelection(printQty);
            //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
            String printerName = "PDF reDirect v2";

            System.Printing.PrintQueue queue = new System.Printing.LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue(printerName);
            printDlg.PrintQueue = queue;




            printDlg.PrintVisual(myGrid, "");

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this question will help you. You can look at the Measure and Arrange methods, probably smth in there.

[Print Grid which generated dynamically in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040735/print-grid-which-generated-dynamically-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Does this code print for you anything? If it does, there's something wrong with the measurements. Also, don't forget that the grid has to be rendered at the moment you're trying to print it using PrintVisual method.

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    dialog.PrintVisual(myGrid, "CustomDescription");
}
```