# How to print a table in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I program in WPF. 
I built a table (DataGrid) with lots of data **(6 columns and 100 rows)** and I was wondering how do I print it ?

I did a lot of searching about this and I have not found a solution for this one.
When I print, it prints only one page for me **(about 30 rows of the table)** and that's it.

Here's the code that should work on the DataGrid table:

```
        System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog Printdlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

        if ((bool)Printdlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            System.Windows.Size pageSize = new System.Windows.Size(Printdlg.PrintableAreaWidth, Printdlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
            // sizing of the element.
            MyDataGrid.Measure(pageSize);
            MyDataGrid.Arrange(new Rect(5, 5, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
            Printdlg.PrintVisual(MyDataGrid, Title);
        }
```

Can someone write me a simple code how to print a DataGrid table correctly?
Thank you!!

Comment: I think this might be of some help for you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ebb07af-253b-46f5-949d-5230ecc1b53c/wpf-printdialogprintvisual-doesnt-print-all-the-pages?forum=wpf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040735/print-grid-which-generated-dynamically-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks for the links. But still not working. 
I am looking to print a DataGrid and it's not relevant. 

Does anyone can write maybe the code for it ?

Comment: I personally prefer to print just the data, and not the UI control wrapping it. If you really want to print the control with all the data, you probably have to render it first at an unlimited size (such as disabling virtualization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Print DataGrid in WPF you have to take  and use given code.

**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="dataGrid1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGoldenrodYellow" AlternationCount="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="100" Height="50" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>


            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Make" Binding="{Binding Path=Make}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Path=Model}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Print" Click="OnDataGridPrinting"  Width="80" Height="30" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Code**

```
private void OnDataGridPrinting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog Printdlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        if ((bool)Printdlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            Size pageSize = new Size(Printdlg.PrintableAreaWidth, Printdlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
            // sizing of the element.
            dataGrid1.Measure(pageSize);
            dataGrid1.Arrange(new Rect(5, 5, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
            Printdlg.PrintVisual(dataGrid1, Title);
        }
}
```

This is tested code.

Comment: Obviously I added the XAML code. 
As I said it works for me only on single page. But, how do we solve the problem? I have not found an answer!! (As I said, I looked at all links and they all refer to other sites with no real answer) 

If anyone has an answer with the code I would like if he could write it here ( without having to refer me to other sites) 
Thanks!