# Printing a fixed width string by appending spaces in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am creating a printable report in WPF which has multiple columns. I need to place each column data under its header. Using Courier New, I can fill up the empty column area with standard space character and report is perfectly aligned. But as soon as I use a Unicode font to support non-English characters, the variable spacing of different characters breaks the alignment. (This is using RAW Printing)

To overcome this, I am trying Graphics printing using System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument. To fill up the empty area remaining after a column's text, I am using \u200A (Hair Space, lowest width space) in repetition until the compounded string's width reaches the desired column width. However, this is not resulting in perfectly aligned columns.

Here is a reduced example:

- String1: Say 40 Hair Spaces
- String2: 'WW' (Width, say 18)
- Deduct 18 from 40, append String2 with 22 Hair Spaces

Printing String1 and String2 one below the other results in slightly mis-aligned columns (See output image below)

[image: Print Output]

```
        //Create a string of 40 Hair Spaces (/u200A)
        string TempString = Functions.GetEmptyGraphic(40);

        //Add to print data
        string PrintString = TempString + "|\n";

        //Create another string with WW
        TempString = "WW";
        //Measure length of WW
        int StringWidth = Functions.GetGraphicWidth(TempString);
        //Append WW String with remaining width to make upto total width of 40
        TempString += Functions.GetEmptyGraphic(40 - StringWidth);

        //Add WW + 22 Hair Space string to print queue
        PrintString += TempString + "\n";

        //Print to PDF
        GraphicPrinterHelper pg = new GraphicPrinterHelper();
        pg.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
        pg.DocumentName = "Test Document";
        pg.PrintData = PrintString;
        pg.Print();
```

Function to measure string width:

```
    public static int GetGraphicWidth(string str)
    {
        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(str, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Arial Unicode MS"), 10, Brushes.Black, new NumberSubstitution(), TextFormattingMode.Ideal);
        return (int)ft.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;
    }
//I have tried using TextFormattingMode.Display also, which results in even bigger mis-alignments.
```

Function to generate empty hair space string

```
 public static string GetEmptyGraphic(int GraphicLength)
    {
        string tmpstr = "\u200A";
        int size = GetGraphicWidth(tmpstr);
        while (size < GraphicLength)
        {
            tmpstr += ThinSpace;
            size = GetGraphicWidth(tmpstr);
        }
        return tmpstr;
    }
```

Code to print:

```
public void Print(string _PrintData)
    {
PrintData = _PrintData;

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 827, 1169);
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterName;
        pd.DocumentName = "Test Print";
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 65;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 50;

        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        pd.Print();
        pd.Dispose();
    }

private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
ev.Graphics.DrawString(PrintData, EnVar.GraphicFont, Brushes.Black, xPos, yPos, new StringFormat());
}
```

I have tried dozens of different Unicode fonts but nothing results in perfect alignment. I tried searching for Monospace+Unicode fonts with support of non-English languages (Devanagari to be specific), but could not find any.

Comment: ... Why are you doing it this way? You're not going to make this work. If you need a character drawn at a particular set of coordinates, then draw it at those coordinates (e.g. using `Graphics.DrawString`). Don't try and pad things with spaces. WPF has a lot of support for printing, and should be able to construct e.g. a `Grid` (which will align things properly for you), and then print it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040735/print-grid-which-generated-dynamically-in-wpf

Comment: The reason of doing it this way is because the application must support RAW Printing by default as maximum users are using dot matrix printer. Using grid printing significantly slows the print process on dot matrix. But if there is no way to make this work, I may have to go the grid printing way.